# Difference between Sum and Aggregate in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What is the diffrence between the two functions: Sum / Aggregate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can essentially think of Sum as one particular type of Aggregate, but there are many other types.

Some examples of Aggregate might be to multiply every single value, or to add strings rather than numbers.

The reason that Sum exists in addition to Aggregate is simply that Sum is one of the more common types of Aggregate functions, so it was worthwhile to add an additional function for that case.

Answer (score 10):

The `Sum` operation is a specialization of `Aggregate`.  The `Aggregate` operation is a way of collapsing a collection into a single value by applying a delegate that reduces a pair of values into a single value.  `Sum` is essentially calling `Aggregate` with the `+` function / operator

Comment: I'll second that!

Answer (score 4):

`Aggregate` is much more flexible. It can be used on a wide number of types (to build strings for example). `Sum` has a very specific purpose (to add numbers).

Answer (score 1):

> Sum method in Linq Operates only on numerical data type (int,float etc) where as
>   Aggregate method can be operated on numerical data type as well as
>   string data type.

```
string[] countries = { "Brazil", "Argentina", "England", "Spain"};
string result = countries.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
//result="Brazil,Argentina,England"

int[] Numbers = { 2, 3, 4 };
int aggregate= Numbers.Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);
//aggregate=24
```